# querying deeply nested children in firebase

Tags: javascript, json, firebase

Given the data structure below (exported from firebase):

```
{
"users" : {
  "123456789" : {
    "email" : "test@gmail.com",
    "name" : "test",
       "listings" : {
          "adtitle" : {
            "description" : "this is a description",
            "skilltype" : "painter"
          },
          "adtitle2" : {
            "description" : "this is a second description",
            "skilltype" : "painter"
          }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to run the following query:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://my.firebaseio.com/users");
ref.orderByChild("listings/adtitle/skilltype").equalTo("painter").on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.key());
});
```

but get the following error on console:

```
Error: Query.orderByChild failed: First argument was an invalid key: "listings/adtitle/skilltype".  Firebase keys must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "/", "[", or "]").
```

can anyone see where I'm going wrong? I think this is the correct way to query nested data in firebase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ability to query on deeper level properties was [introduced in Firebase JavaScript SDK 2.3](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-09-24-atomic-writes-and-more.html). If you're targeting Android or iOS the feature was introduced in version 2.4 of those SDKs.

Make sure you're using that version (or a newer one).

*Note that I don't consider this an answer, but the question comes around repeatedly (see [this one from yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36216583/update-all-values-firebase-error#comment60066336_36216583)) and without an answer I cannot mark the duplicates.*

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, could you please answer one small more question? if i want to retrieve adtitle as a string from the above structure how would i do that?

Comment: Since you're querying for a hard-coded path 'listings/adtitle/skilltype', you can also use a hard-coded string 'adtitle'

Comment: each time a user is added to the database they will have different number of ads with different "ad titles". Ultimately I want to find all the users in the database with the skilltype painter and display all the "ad titles"

Comment: That won't work with your current data structure. You **cannot** query on `listings/$ad/skilltype`. You'll need to instead create a list of ads, query that and then look up the listing. Or maybe even a list of ads-by-skilltype and look it up there. See https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html and https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html

Comment: Thanks very much! you have been of great help!